# Why <C-O> is not working with noremap!?

Tags: vim

I have this mapping:

```
noremap! <F6> <c-o> :SCCompile<cr>
```

But when I press <kbd>F6</kbd> in insert mode, it just input ":SCCompile\n" in the buffer instead of going to normal mode to execute a command.

It works with `map!` but not with `noremap!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting that you say it works with `map!` because I can't get it to work with `map!` either. We might be using different versions; however, the appropriate way to do this is to remove the space after `<C-o>` like this:

```
noremap! <F6> <c-o>:SCCompile<cr>
```

`<c-o>` in insert mode takes one normal command and a space counts.

Comment: It was just the space indeed.